# Display Triggered JavaScript Events

Tags: javascript, list, events

I am working on a website that uses masonry. I know that the masonry rebuilds itself when the window width changes and I want to be able to trigger that rebuilding at will, like when one of the elements' height is changed. The problem is I don't see any event listeners related to the window's width that I can copy the code from. Is there a way I can see which events are being triggered at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome Developer Tools (press F12 within Chrome), go to the Sources tab.

In the right hand pane, expand `> Event Listener Breakpoints` and tick the ones you want to break on.

Alternatively, if it is using jQuery event handling, you can install the [jQuery Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi?hl=en) extension for Chrome Devtools, and it gives you a `jQuery Events` tab in the right hand column on the Elements tab. That shows you what events are bound to using jQuery for the selected element. Try selecting the `<html>` tag or the `<body>` tag and see if you can find it there.

One final option is to search in the JS you are using for the string "resize".

Comment: You may also find the [Visual Event](https://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) bookmarklet helpful as well. It's quite nice. Look at all the boxes in the top left hand corner when you run it, see if there is a resize handler listed.

Comment: Hi @GregL , thanks for answering! None of the methods work though. The Chrome Developer Tools don't have `> Event Listener Breakpoints`. There are `Event Listeners` which I don't really understand and I can't tick breakpoints there. There is also `DOM Breakpoints`, but there it just says "No Breakpoints". The jQuery Debugger and Visual Event bookmarklet both don't detect anything. In the .js files there are many resizes and from what I understand they have no effect on the dynamic rebuilding.

Comment: Also if the trigger was related to resize it would trigger when I changed the window's height too, but height changing doesn't do anything.

Comment: You were looking on the Elements tab. The "Event Listener Breakpoints" is on the Sources tab: http://i.imgur.com/lRjJf9v.png